# How to statically compile gerbv for Heroku

Tags: gcc, static, linker, libtool

I'm trying to compile [gerbv 2.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gerbv/files/) so that I can include it in my Heroku bin directory, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I've tried various combinations of:

```
CFLAGS='-static  -static-libgcc  -static-libstdc++' ./configure
./configure --enable-static
./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no
```

But after running `make` I always get:

```
src/gerbv: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x401fe83e54660a42e80e4c529fde85799728cdcb, not stripped
```

I'm running out of ideas. Anyone have any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because the system libraries, or the gcc runtime is linked shared.
Use the "ldd" utility to see what is being dynamically linked.

ldd src/gerbv

A shared runtime is probably what you want, but if you want the runtimes to be static, there may be an option for that if you have a static runtime installed.

Comment: You're right, and in the end I just used ldd to identify the shared libraries I needed and then ran them via exec /lib/ld.config.so so that I can override the library path.